# Under what condition is thefollowing function differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, differential-geometry

Suppose I have a $R(\mu)$ which defines a region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. One simple example of $R(\mu)$ could be $\mu B$, where $B$ is a box in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I defined the function
$$
G(\mu) = \int_{R(\mu)} f(\mathbf{z}) d \mathbf{z},
$$
where $f$ is a smooth function. 
I am convinced that $G$ is differentiable as long as $R(\mu)$ is defined ``nicely''. But I am not sure what are the required conditions for this or to prove this rigorously. I would greatly appreciate any comments or suggestions. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you really mean $\mu \in \mathbb R^n$, or $\mu \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Either way, the most obvious situation where this is true is when $R(\mu)$ can be parametrized smoothly; i.e. there is some smooth family of diffeomorphisms $\phi_\mu : R(0) \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\phi_\mu(R(0)) = R(\mu).$ In this case you can apply the change of variables formula to $G(\mu)$ to make the integral domain indepedent of $\mu$, then move the derivative inside the integral.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you for your comments. The typo is fixed now. Also do you think this is possible for more general case (than the situation you described)?

Comment: My feeling is that the only case in which this is true for a good reason is  for a parametrized family in some sense. The regularity can certainly be weakened from smoothness: if you use some ideas from geometric measure theory then you probably only need $\phi_\mu$ to be bi-Lipschitz, and the family itself simply differentiable. There will be other cases where it is true "by accident" ($R$ jumping around discontinuously in just the right way), but I don't think there is any useful way of characterizing these.